# Using "times" font for entire document, but cannot do bold math font; how to change font for specific equation

Tags: fonts, bold, math-fonts, times, timesfont

I am writing a PhD thesis according to a template. It uses the "times" font, which apparently is a uni requirement. It turns out that this prevents be from using bold font in equations. This is especially true when I do section headings. E.g.

```
\subsection{The phosphatase can be characterised through the parameter $p_{prod}$ only}
```

becomes:

[image]

with "p_{prod}" being in a thin font. I have worked a lot on this, but have not succeeded yet. Just marking `$p_{prod}$` as bold using e.g.`\boldmath` doesn't work. The closest I have got is adding

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

at the beginning of my document. This solves it, but changes the font of *all* equations (which would not be too bad, but it means that some become too long for the pages, causing other problems). Ideally I would want the effect of `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, but limited to one specific equation. This I have not figured out how to do (for normal text I have, as I was having a similar problem with greek letters).

Doing `\textit{p\textsubscript{prod}}` does also give some result, but it seems better to actually use math font...

I am trying to add a MWE, which is this one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\begin{document}

\section*{Formula: $p_{prod}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Unfortunately, Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF is a 1000 lines long file that I am mostly unfamiliar with, so I am not really sure if this is helpful.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example such that we also know which document class to address this for.

Comment: do you mean you are using mathptm package for math currently? Honestly I wouldn't, better to use newtxmath (or stix2) and adjust anything if needed. mathptm made sense targetting a 1990s PostScript laser printer font set, but now ....

Comment: I tried adding an MWE, but not sure how helpful it is.

I tried something similar to in the link previously. But I think the problem is that the font I use do not have bold math letters, basically I need to figure out how to change the font only.

Comment: Try with `\boldsymbol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Formula: \boldmath$p_{\mathrm{prod}}$}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

and your class also supports `xelatex` which is the better choice:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbered,print,index]{PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Formula: \boldmath$p_{\symrm{prod}}$}
    
\end{document}
```

The class defines XITS for text and math.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot :)